# React - delay heavy sub components rendering

Tags: performance, reactjs, frontend, react-router

I'm using React and React Router, and on some pages, I have some big lists rendered (as sub components) of the pages. When clicking on a link to change the page, it waits for all the subcomponents to be rendered which implies a delay between the click and the visual feedback. Is there a simple way not to wait for some sub components to be rendered?

I'm looking for a best practice, but maybe using a boolean and a `setTimeout()` is the only way. Thx.

Comment: I would avoid manually delaying rendering, you could possibly try something like lazy loading? so only rendering the items in the list if they are in view? or a similar approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have big lists of components, you often don't see all of them at the same time. You can use [React Virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/) to actually render only visible components.

Comment: React Virtualized seems a bit overkill for my needs actually... https://github.com/onefinestay/react-lazy-render seemed just fined but is outdated :/

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below:

```js
const LightComponent = () => <div>LightComponent</div>
const HeavyComponent = () => <div>HeavyComponent</div>

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { shouldRenderHeavyComponent: false };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ shouldRenderHeavyComponent: true });
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log("Render", this.state.shouldRenderHeavyComponent);
    return (
      <div>
        <LightComponent/>
        { this.state.shouldRenderHeavyComponent && <HeavyComponent/> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, it's quite the same as using a setTimeout, plus, I'm not a big fan of a setState in the componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenges. Finally I discovered this wonderful library, doing the trick for me: https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite